# Error in PHPUnit but not in app when updating to Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm updating from Laravel 5.3 to 5.4

I get my composer update working fine, and it seems that my app is ok.

But when I run my tests with PHPUnit, all tests fails.

EDIT:

Now, based on patricus response, I  installed browser-kit-testing and made everything required on the docs.

Issue is still happening...

Here are the new stacks:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::setRequest() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request, null given, called in /laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php on line 139

/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php:768
/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php:139
/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php:96
/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php:70
/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php:294
/laravel/vendor/sentry/sentry-laravel/src/Sentry/SentryLaravel/SentryLaravelServiceProvider.php:83
/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:678
/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:565
/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:702
/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:105
/laravel/vendor/sentry/sentry-laravel/src/Sentry/SentryLaravel/SentryLaravelServiceProvider.php:45
/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:28
/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:912
/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:86
/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:30
/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:524
/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:762
/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:745
/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:746
/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/BootProviders.php:17
/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:208
/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:160
/laravel/tests/BrowserKitTest.php:24
/laravel/vendor/laravel/browser-kit-testing/src/TestCase.php:95
/laravel/vendor/laravel/browser-kit-testing/src/TestCase.php:70
/laravel/tests/functional/RoundRobinTreeTest.php:22
```

Here is my RoundRobinTest:

```
class RoundRobinTreeTest extends BrowserKitTest
{
....
}
```

and in my tests folder, I copied the old TestCase.php to BrowserKitTest.php

```
    use Laravel\BrowserKitTesting\TestCase as BaseTestCase;


abstract class BrowserKitTest extends BaseTestCase
{
....
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code ?

Comment: well, it is 100% of my code that fails, so, I don't really know what to show... Which class do you want to know?

Comment: Is it hosted on github ? you can share the link of it.

Comment: nop, it is a private rep :( but I can share any code you need

Comment: Try to run test files individually so as you get to know in which file you are getting error and send its code

Comment: All my tests sends this same error... if I run it individually it should be the same no?

Comment: Make sure your tests extends `TestCase` class. If it does I assume you have a `setUp()` method in your test. Make sure you call `parent::setUp()`. A snippet of test would be great.

Comment: What version of PHPUnit are you running? PHPUnit 5.7+ is required by Laravel 5.4.

Comment: yep, I use 5.7.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel 5.4 updated the testing framework it uses. Laravel 5.4 uses Laravel Dusk, whereas Laravel 5.3 uses Symfony's browserkit component.

The Laravel 5.3 browserkit testing functionality was extracted to its own package ([laravel/browser-kit-testing](https://github.com/laravel/browser-kit-testing)), so that you can require the package and have your 5.3 tests work in 5.4. The [upgrade instructions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade) in Laravel's documentation explain more.

Basically, pull in the `laravel/browser-kit-testing` package, and change your `TestCase` file to extend `Laravel\BrowserKitTesting\TestCase`, and your tests should work as they did in 5.3.

---

#### Edit

As best I can tell, you're using the wrong `Kernel`.

In your stacktrace, `Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php:139` is this line:

```
$guard->setRequest($this->app->refresh('request', $guard, 'setRequest'));
```

That means `$this->app->refresh('request', $guard, 'setRequest')` is returning null (according to your error message "null given"). `$this->app->refresh()` will return null when the item being refreshed (`'request'`) has not been bound yet.

Earlier in your stacktrace shows that your `tests/BrowserKitTest.php` file is calling `bootstrap()` on the `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel`. The problem with this is that there is nothing in the Http kernel's bootstrapers that binds the `'request'` instance.

You should be calling `bootstrap()` on the `Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel`, as one of its bootstrappers is `Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\SetRequestForConsole`, which does provide a binding for the `'request'` instance.

Additionally, the Console kernel is the kernel specified by the original `TestCase` file provided by Laravel.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, ok, I installed laravel/browser-kit-testing, and make my TestCase extends  Laravel\BrowserKitTesting\TestCase as you said. Issue still remains :(